# Eloquent complex relationship for a chat message system in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am writing a chat system and I have the following tables:

**chat_conversations:** `id, name`

**chat_messages:** `id, chat_conversation_id, message, deleted_at`

**chat_message_user:** `id, chat_message_id, user_id, is_sender, seen, deleted_at`

**chat_conversation_user:** `id, user_id, chat_conversation_id, is_owner`

I want the messages to be linked to the users seperately hence the `chat_message_user` such that each message can be deleted individually but remain visible for the other user(s) in the chat. For example, if I am chatting with someone else, and I want to 'delete' the conversation on my end only, I want the other person to still have that chat history on their end.

I want to be able to query the conversations that belong to the auth::user and append the messages that only THEY can see (the ones where the chat_message_user is NOT soft deleted)

```
Auth::user()->conversations
```

`User` Model:

```
...

public function conversations()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(ChatConversation::class)
               ->withTimestamps();
}

...
```

`ChatConversation` Model:

```
protected $appends = ['messages'];

public function messages()
{
   return $this
       ->hasMany(ChatMessage::class)
       ->whereHas('user') //I want whereHas('user') to reference only the user id from the Auth::user()
       ->get();
}

public function getMessagesAttribute()
{
   return $this->messages();
}
...
```

Currently, I am trying to use a whereHas('user') on my messages method but in order for it to work as I intended, I need to pass in a user id... Ideally I just want to be able to reference the Auth::user->id from the start of the query... But if I have a parameter on the messages method, it will not append...

```
->whereHas('user', function ($query) use ($user_id) {
    $query->where('user_id', $user_id);
})
```

In a nut shell, I want the conversation to return with it all of the messages that belong to the current user which are not deleted for that particular user via the chat_message_user pivot table.

Comment: I'm also building a chat system but I haven't considered removing messages for only some users. I would add a new object called hide_message_from_user with a one to many. Then you can load the relationship and make that a condition where the relation is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a relationship on the conversation to only query the messages for the authenticated user.

In `ChatConversation`

```
public function userMessages()
{
   return $this
       ->hasMany(ChatMessage::class)
       ->whereHas('user', function ($query) {
           $query->where('user_id', Auth::id());
        });
}
```

Note that without calling `->get()`, this is an actuall laravel relationship and not a collection. Now, you can query your messages easily once you have the `$conversation` object:

```
$conversation->userMessages; // Collection of all the messages for the user in the conversation

$conversation->userMessages()->limit(10)->get(); // Only query 10 messages
```

---

You can also load the messages with the conversations using [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads):

```
User::find(1)->conversations()->with(['userMessages' => function ($query) {
  $query->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->limit(10);
}]);
```

Comment: Technically I tried this method but I wasn't able to get it to work at the time, most likely because of other factors, however I revisited this method and essentially it works.

The problem with this method is that I cannot "append" the user messages to the conversation in the same query for example:
User::find(1)->conversations() should return the conversations with their respective userMessages as you defined.

Now, I need to query for the userMessages collection seperately and merge it with my conversation collection.

However, I do see a benefit in keeping the messages seperate...